# Problem with JSON Response from ASP.NET MVC in Some Browsers

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-2, forms

I'm using jQuery's form plugin (as suggested in a number of threads like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956882/asp-net-mvc-json-open-dialog-box-problem)) to make an Ajax post to a .NET MVC controller and consume the JSON I get back. It works just fine in Chrome, but in some other browsers, including Firefox 3, the form submit results in a "Save or Open this file" dialog box. The JavaScript looks like:

```
var options = {
            dataType: "json",
            clearForm: true,
            beforeSubmit: hideUpdateField,
            success: handleNewsPostSuccess
        };

        $('div#Updates form').ajaxForm(options);
```

and meat of the controller response is:

```
Object response = new { html = RenderPartialViewToString("DisplayNewsPost", np), newpoints = points.ToString() };
return Json(response, "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

What am I missing? It's like the submit event isn't getting attached in Firefox and the other problem browsers. I tried making my own submit action using [ajaxSubmit](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#api) instead with a return false in it, but no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use different MIME type for response; simple `text/plain` should work. I believe FF is confused by unknown `application/*` MIME type and thus assumes it's some application-specific data that are best downloaded as separate file.

Alternatively, you can experiment with `Content-Disposition` header, setting it to `inline`. Firefox should be obeying it, but IIRC there might be some problems with it on IE.

Comment: I would consider this a bug in FireFox's implementation, but you work with what you got, not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're hitting the same problem, but [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842399/jquery-ajax-json-call-to-js-file-causes-browser-to-ask-save-open) may help you

Answer (score 0):

The Json method already sets the proper content type so you don't need to repeat it:

```
return Json(response);
```

But from the behavior you are describing (Save As dialog) I suspect that the form is actually not posted using AJAX but a normal POST. This could be due to the fact that the DOM was not ready when you applied the `.ajaxForm` function. Make sure that you are ajaxifying the form inside `$(document).ready`:

```
$(function() {
    var options = {
        dataType: "json",
        clearForm: true,
        beforeSubmit: hideUpdateField,
        success: handleNewsPostSuccess
    };
    $('div#Updates form').ajaxForm(options);
});
```

Also if in your `handleNewsPostSuccess` callback you recreate the form in the DOM the `ajaxForm` might no longer apply to it and the second time you try to submit it will perform a normal POST.